# Android: Eclipse - Not showing exceptions

Tags: android, eclipse

After installing an update on Android SDK and moving to Eclipse 3.6, when an exception occurs while my code is running, I'm only prompted for what seems to be Android source code, in stread of showing the line in my code and the exception details in logcat.

I now resort to try..catch - ing everything, but it's not practical.

Why is it prompting for the source code?

Many thanks for any help!!

Nothing in Log Cat:
[image: Nothing in the log cat]

Prompting for source file:
[image: Prompting for source file]

Answer (score 7):

I've solved this after waiting days to post this. All that changed is that when I get the prompt for source, I just click Run / Resume and it will throw the exception stack onto logcat.

Maybe this will help somebody else.

Comment: Yep this is useful, thanks.  I had to press resume several times - and then I get a stack trace with the java.lang.RuntimeException (not useful as my code isn't involved), followed by a 'Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException'.  This caused by stack trace actually includes my code - and double clicking the entry takes me to the error.  Hurrah! Problem solved.

Comment: Many thanks for the solution, same problem was going to drive me nuts.

Comment: You should mark this question as the answer. This was bugging me so much!

Comment: that simple and here i thought id have to try re-installing next! thank you, please mark.